# How to negate this regex

Tags: html, regex

The following regex will do validation for the P. O. Box is entered in the text box,

```
\b[P|p](OST|ost)?[.\s-]+[O|o](FFICE|ffice)?[.\s-]+[B|b](OX|ox)\b
```

i want to negate this so as to detect whether user is not entering P. O. Box it in the text box,
I know that we can do it by using javascript also, but my platform has different form structure, its demandware form, where i have regex as the field attribute.
We can submit a regex in this field and it will validate it automatically.Any idea?

Comment: That's not how validation works. Surely you want to use the regex as-is, then demandware will notify if the entered value doesn't match.

Comment: Could be the OP wants to preclude addresses that contain PO Boxes

Comment: Is this for US addresses ONLY?

Comment: @OrangeDog Thanks for quick reply, but its not working for me in demandware platform,"then demandware will notify if the entered value doesn't match." is correct but i dont want user to enter the p o box anymore

Comment: you might want to consider using a case-insensitive match rather than all those upper/lower case variants. It would simplify the pattern significantly.

Comment: If you don't want people to enter anything, then the pattern is `/^$/`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now. You have just one text box for the whole address?

Comment: Also, when trying to match `P` or `p`, use `[Pp]`, not `[P|p]`. The latter will also match a literal `|`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend *not* attempting to do this with a regular expression. It is *way* too easy to defeat<sup>1</sup>. Instead, you need to out source the problem to someone who knows what they are doing. In this case, [since you are dealing with US addresses only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104052/how-to-negate-this-regex/18104555#comment26502776_18104052), the [USPS](https://www.usps.com/).

So, you should use the [USPS address standarization/verification API](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information.htm). You can submit an address, and it will return to you a "cleaned" version of that address. It will tell you whether or not the address is valid. And if it is a post office box, it will return it to you in a standardized format and now you don't need a regular expression that can be defeated, now you only need a *simple* string match. And, as an added bonanza, you'll get a *standardized* and *validated* representation of the delivery address *reducing*<sup>2</sup> the possibility of error.

I recognize I am sidestepping your actual engineering question. But part of engineering is abandoning solutions that are the wrong path. You need to validate addresses. So validate addresses rather than trying to build a state machine that can detect *some* inputs that represent post office boxes but will fail on others. And the USPS provides a validation service and they *are* the authoritative experts here.

<sup>1</sup>: I am not saying that you'll face adversaries, just you'll face all the creative, sloppy, lazy ways that people have for entering in their addresses.

<sup>2</sup>: But not eliminating.

Comment: Ya i have already pointed it out to my client, even i can defeat it with some combination,but still if i want to show some workaround can you suggest something

Comment: @user2408578: No, I think it's the wrong approach to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negative lookaround:  `(?!pattern)`.

In this case

```
 (?! \b[P|p](OST|ost)?[.\s-]+[O|o](FFICE|ffice)?[.\s-]+[B|b](OX|ox)\b )
```

For reference:

[Regex lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Presumably the regex is tested against the whole value. This regex will validate that it doesn't _start_ with a PO Box, not that the value doesn't _contain_ one.

Comment: @streetpc yes you are correct,you can validate it quickly on http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, help me

Answer (score 0):

If the regex flavor is JavaScript's, then you can use [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*?\b[Pp](OST|ost)?[.\s-]+[Oo](FFICE|ffice)?[.\s-]+[Bb](OX|ox)\b)
```

Comment: Umm its what i m using but is not working, or can you check at www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html,

Comment: Yes I forgot the `^`, fixed.

Comment: Also, because of the `+` in `[.\s-]+` before the `[Oo]`, it will allow `"PO Box"`. To fix this, you can just replace `+` with `*`: `^(?!.*?\b[Pp](OST|ost)?[.\s-]*[Oo](FFICE|ffice)?[.\s-]+[Bb](OX|ox)\b)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?:[^p]+|\Bp+|p(?!(?:ost)?[.\s-]+o(?:ffice)?[.\s-]+box\b))+$
```

The idea is to test only substrings that begin with "p" (for more performances). To make this check case insensitive, you can add `(?i)` at the begining of the pattern:

```
^(?i)(?:[^p]+|\Bp+|p(?!(?:ost)?[.\s-]+o(?:ffice)?[.\s-]+box\b))+$
```